# Multiprocessing and Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, multiprocessing

I asked a similar question before, but got no helpful response so I will try to make things more clear.

What I am looking for is to run a multithreaded or preferably multiprocessing approach to a certain linux command. If anyone is familiar with [Picard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/picard/), I am wanting to run an earlier version on a bam file and at the same time run a newer version on the same bam file. The idea is to test how much quicker the newer version is and if it gives the same result.

My major problem is that I have no idea how to implement multiprocessing on a Popen command. E.g.

```
cmd1 = ['nice', 'time', 'java', '-Xmx6G', '-jar', '/comparison/old_picard/MarkDuplicates.jar', 'I=/comparison/old.bam', 'O=/comparison/old_picard/markdups/old.dupsFlagged.bam', 'M=/comparison/old_picard/markdups/old.metrics.txt', 'TMP_DIR=/comparison', 'VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=LENIENT', 'ASSUME_SORTED=true']
cmd2 = ['nice', 'time', 'java', '-Xmx6G', '-jar', '/comparison/new_picard/MarkDuplicates.jar', 'I=/comparison/new.bam', 'O=/comparison/new_picard/markdups/new.dupsFlagged.bam', 'M=/comparison/new_picard/markdups/new.metrics.txt', 'TMP_DIR=/comparison', 'VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=LENIENT', 'ASSUME_SORTED=true']

c1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
c2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And then I have a timer function:

```
def timeit(c):
    past = time.time()
    results = [c.communicate()]
    present = time.time()
    total = present - past
    results.append(total)
    return results
```

What I WANT to do is this:

```
p = Process(target=timeit, args=(c1,c2))
p.start()
p.join()
```

However I get "Popen object not iterable" error. Does anyone have a better idea than what I have now? I don't want to go off in a completely different direction only to hit another wall. In summary I want to run c1 on one cpu and c2 on the other at the same time, Please help!

Comment: Why do you want to run them at the same time? I doubt you'll get meaningful results from this.

Comment: Have you considered running them sequentially, so that you can actually mimic the process itself? CPU is not the only shared resource, so if this is a memory-intensive or disk-intensive operation, you might have one process or thread that's winning out and has the appearance of being quicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing the subprocess.Popen (which will run them serially instead of in parallel when it is first defined), pass the *command*:

```
import time
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process

cmd1 = ['nice', 'time', 'java', '-Xmx6G', '-jar', '/comparison/old_picard/MarkDuplicates.jar', 'I=/comparison/old.bam', 'O=/comparison/old_picard/markdups/old.dupsFlagged.bam', 'M=/comparison/old_picard/markdups/old.metrics.txt', 'TMP_DIR=/comparison', 'VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=LENIENT', 'ASSUME_SORTED=true']
cmd2 = ['nice', 'time', 'java', '-Xmx6G', '-jar', '/comparison/new_picard/MarkDuplicates.jar', 'I=/comparison/new.bam', 'O=/comparison/new_picard/markdups/new.dupsFlagged.bam', 'M=/comparison/new_picard/markdups/new.metrics.txt', 'TMP_DIR=/comparison', 'VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=LENIENT', 'ASSUME_SORTED=true']

def timeit(cmd):
    print cmd
    past = time.time()
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    results = [p.communicate()]
    present = time.time()
    total = present - past
    results.append(total)
    return results

p1 = Process(target=timeit, args=(cmd1,))
p2 = Process(target=timeit, args=(cmd2,))

for p in (p1, p2):
    p.start()
for p in (p1, p2):
    p.join()
```

ETA: While the above solution is the way to do multiprocessing in general, @Jordan is exactly right that you shouldn't use this approach to time two versions of software. Why not run them sequentially?

Comment: These tasks potentially take a long time to run, thus I would be using a shared host machine with more power to run them. If I ran them sequentially (say the old version first) and the machines processor load was low, and then later in a few hours the new version of picard ran but more users had added tasks to the host causing it to go to a high load. Then the second task would run slower just because of the other traffic. Thus there would be no point in timing them, because the stats would not be under equal conditions.

Comment: also how come you didn't put p.join() in the same for loop as p.start()?

Comment: Haha thank you. I didn't put `p.join()` in the same loop because then it wouldn't be in parallel. `p.join()` means "wait for process p to finish". If they were in the same loop, it would start a process, wait for it to finish, start the other process, and wait for it to finish (thus, no parallelization at all)

Comment: Ah yes, I was just reading about that. The python documentation is sometimes difficult to interpret. I have one more thing to ask. And that is how would I neatly present my results? Like say I wanted to print the time of each function after?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
p1 = Process(target=timeit, args=(c1,))
p2 = Process(target=timeit, args=(c2,))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

I don't know where your iteration error is though (what line is it?).

Also, I think you'd be better off running them separately. When you're running them together, you run the risk of one process being given more CPU time and appearing to be faster, even when it isn't.